# validate method inside Backbone Model not being called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Beginning to learn Backbone, trying to do some simple validation inside my Person Model but the validate method doesn't seem to be run when I set a new age. Can anyone explain where i may be going wrong on this? Don't want to move on with my learning until I get this right.

**JS**

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        name: 'John Doe',
        age: 30,
        occupation: 'working'
    },

    validate: function(attrs) {

        console.log(attrs);

        if ( attrs.age < 0 ) {
            return 'Age must be positive, stupid';
        }

        if ( ! attrs.name ) {
            return 'Every person must have a name, you fool.';
        }

    },

    work: function() {
        return this.get('name') + ' is working.';
    }

});
```

Currently I am just getting and setting values in the console, so:

```
var person = new Person({
    name: 'Lady Madonna',
    age: 23
});

person.on('error', function(model, error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

When I set age to be a negative value the validate method doesn't take effect:

```
person.set('age', -55);
```

Comment: where you are calling these function? And how you are calling them?

Comment: Please add an example of how you set the new value.

Comment: I understand that version 0.9.10+ now requests that {validate: true} be passed but Im not sure where this is added?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Model validation [changed in Backbone 0.9.10](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog):

> Model validation is now only enforced by default in Model#save and no longer enforced by default upon construction  or in Model#set, unless the `{validate:true}` option is passed.

and note that

> Model validation now fires *invalid* event instead of *error*.

So your code should be written as

```
var person = new Person({
    name: 'Lady Madonna',
    age: 23
});

person.on('invalid', function(model, error){
    console.log(error);
});

person.set('age', -55, {validate : true});
```

And a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/aUxdS/

Comment: this still sets the age as -55 though?

Comment: @styler No, if validation fails, the attributes are not set. http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/aUxdS/2/ for example

Comment: ah ok so the defaults are protected but the new person objects age will still be set yeah?

Comment: @styler If you try to set an invalid value with `{validate : true}`, the  change won't be recorded. If you don't pass `{validate : true}`, the attribute will indeed be set.

Comment: your fiddle is off `validate: function(attrs) {...` 
should be `validate: function (attrs, options) {...}`

Comment: @pixel67 I'm not sure I understand your comment : there is an `options` argument available in the method signature but it's optional and not needed in this case, so it's omitted.

Comment: when I ran your fiddle, I replaced the console.log to alerts and it didn't work, now when I ran them with the alerts they worked, not sure why it didn't work the first time, and I didn't know the `options` argument was optional. Thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 3):

By default, `validate()` gets called before a call to `save()` method. If you also want it to be called before `set()`, you should specify the { validate : true } option, for example:

```
person.set({ age : -55 }, { validate : true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I wrote a while back.
Hope it helps:

So lets say you have a model called Animal:

```
var Animal = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:  {
        name: '',
        speech: ''
    },
    validate: function(attribs) {
        if(attribs.name === ''){
            return "Your animal does not have a name.";
        }
    },
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('New Animal creation');
        this.on("change:name", function() {
            console.log("Change captured");
        });
        this.on("error", function(model, error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
});
```

So when somewhere in javascript you do this:

```
var dog = new Animal();
dog.set('speech', 'kef');
```

You will receive the following message / error:

```
"Your Animal does not have a name."
```

Now the validation will not be called when creating the new object 'dog'.
You really need to set it as wel using the dog.set().

Otherwise it will not produce an error.

By changing the value later on it might also not give this error.
(you really need to use set I guess).

However you can always check if the model is in Valid state like this:

```
Model.isValid().
```

This will return a false when the Model is not valid.
So this:

```
var dog = new Animal();
dog.isValid(); //would return a 'false' 

dog.set({
    'speech': 'kef',
    'name': 'fido'
});
dog.isValid(); //would return a 'true'
```

Hope this helps!